# Hidden checkbox inside a details html tag

Tags: css, html

There seems to be a bug in the Safari 10.0.3 implementation of the `details` html tag:

I wrote a small jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tqtaea19/) to explain it. Here is my html code:

```
<details open>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"> Item 1
  </div>

  <div class="hidden">
    <input type="checkbox"> Item 2
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"> Item 3
  </div>

</details>
```

and my css:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Here is the problem: the first time I load this page. When I click on one of the checkboxes, the summary tag will momentarily move down one item. And then, it doesn't seem to happen any other time I click on the checkboxes.

It also doesn't seem to happen:

- when the details tag is closed to start with.
- in Chrome

Has anyone encountered this and has a solution? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: what summary tag? seems fine to me in safari

Comment: @MichaelCoker By summary tag, I mean the line where "Details" is written.